# Catalina upgrade and Citrix issue

Tags: macbook, citrix-receiver

After I upgraded my MacBook Pro 2015 to Catalina I can't use Citrix anymore.
It throws the error:
You have not chosen to trust "DigiCert Global Root G2", the issuer of the server's security certificate.

Any clue how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/403432-citrix-workspace-app-globalsign-root-ca-post-upgrade-to-catalina-beta/page/11/) and the latest version of Citrix should now work.

However there may be other adjustments needed (for example on the server side) which are outlined in the discussion forum linked above.

Download Link : https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/mac/workspace-app-for-mac-latest.html?_ga=2.228205461.968009163.1570529228-262928685.1570529228